# printf too smart casting from char to int?

Tags: c, casting, printf, byte

Why does the following call:

```
printf("%d %d", 'a', 'b');
```

result in the "correct" `97 98` values?
%d indicates the function has to read 4 bytes of data, and printf shouldn't be able to tell the type of the received arguments (besides the format string), so why isn't the printed number `|a||b||junk||junk|`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: %d is a signed integer, says nothing about the number of bytes involved...

Comment: @leppie:  However, it has to be passed with some definite number of bytes, and `printf` has to pick a certain number of bytes off the stack for it, and these certain numbers have to be the same.

Comment: `'a'` has type `int` not `char`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, the parameters received by `printf` will be of type `int`.

First of all, anything you pass to printf (except the first parameter) undergoes "default promotions", which means (among other things) that `char` and `short` are both promoted to `int` before being passed. So, even if what you were passing really did have type char, by the time it got to `printf` it would have type `int`. In your case, you're using a character literal, which already has type `int` anyway.

The same is true with scanf, and other functions that take variadic parameters.

Second, even without default promotions, character literals in C already have type `int` anyway (§6.4.4.4/10):

> An integer character constant has type int.

So, in this case the values start with type `int`, and aren't promoted--but even if you started with `char`s, something like:

```
char a = 'a';

printf("%d", a);
```

...what `printf` receives would be of type `int`, not type `char` anyway.

Comment: Default promotions?  Really?  Since when do varargs do default promotions?  Isn't it just that the type of a character literal is `int`?

Comment: Yes and no -- yes, a char literal has type `int`, but even if he assigned it to a `char` and passed that, `printf` would still receive an `int`, so it's pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: No promotions are happening here. `'a'` and `'b'` have type `int` in C.

Comment: @R: Gee, thanks! I'm sure nobody else here noticed anything like that. *Closed captioning for the humor impaired*:If "@R" had bothered to read the previous comments, he'd see that everybody else noticed that weeks ago -- and that I already pointed out that/how it's irrelevant.

Comment: @R.. Your point forced me to asked another question: Why is `printf("%d", (char)'a');` working fine? Does `printf` bypass coercion too? Do enlighten. :)

Comment: @ChaZ: Calls to variadic functions subject all the variadic arguments to *default promotions*, which promote all integer types with rank lower than `int` to `int` or `unsigned int` and promote `float` to `double`. It's fundamentally impossible to pass a `char` as a variadic argument.

Comment: @R.. So shall I presume that _promotions_ are happening here?

Comment: In the case of `printf("%d", (char)'a');`, the default promotions, which perhaps would be better described as *mandatory* promotions, result in the `char`-type expression `(char)'a'` being promoted to `int` before being passed to `printf`. In the case of `printf("%d", 'a');`, `'a'` simply has type `int` to begin with.

Comment: Here is a reference link (see section "Default conversions"): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Answer (score 4):

In `C`, a char literal is a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

it prints the DEC ASCII for the characters entered by you.