# C char appears as int when compiling

Tags: c, char, int, printf, compiler-warnings

I'm learning C, and have been trying to make a program that takes user input, and removes any double spaces in it, then prints it out again. We have not done arrays yet so I need to do this char by char. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char c;
    int count;
    count = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        if (c == ' ')
            count++;
        if (c != ' ')
            count = 0;
        if (count <= 0)
            printf("%s", c);
}
```

This code does not work, however. The compiler returns the error

```
:15: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Any help? I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `%c` format specifier to print a single `char`

```
printf("%c", c);
```

The `%s` format specifier tells `printf` to expect a null-terminated char array (aka a string).

The error message refers to `c` having type `int` due to default promotion of arguments (beyond the format string) passed to `printf`.  [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3959702/311966) has a nice description of default promotion; [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255775/311966) explains some of the reasoning for why default promotion is necessary.

Comment: Can you please explain why the error message refers to `int`?

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis Good point.  I've added links to previous threads which contain better explanations than I'd manage

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. That way you can distinguish a `char` read from `EOF` (can't be a legal `char` value, obviously). Not the brightest interface, but compact (and customary by now).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%s` which is used for a string and which expects a terminating NULL character(\0)..

Using `%c` will print you char by char..

Answer (score 0):

Your code has so many problems

- First, you **print a char with `%s`** (which expects a char pointer, i.e. a string)

  In C, char literals are of type `int`, so whether promoted or not, they're always int. In C++, char literals would be of type `char`, but after promotion like other answers said, again they'll be int. A plain `char` variable will also be promoted to int in expressions, and passed as int in vararg functions like `printf`. That's why the compiler warns you that `argument 2 has type ‘int’`, because it's expecting a `char*` and you're passing it an `int`

  → You must use `%c` to print a char
- Your `while` loop's body is only the first if block, because in C block scope is defined by `{}`, not by indentation. So the code will run like this, which is not like what you intended

  ```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
      if (c == ' ')
          count++;
  }
  if (c != ' ')
      count = 0;
  if (count <= 0)
      printf("%s", c);
  ```

  → You need to put the code block in a pair of brackets. And using `else` instead of 2 separate ifs to make it more readable and faster (for dumb compilers)

  ```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
      if (c == ' ')
          count++;
      else
          count = 0;
      if (count <= 0)
          printf("%s", c);
  }
  ```
- `main()` is wrong. The correct versions in C would be

  ```
  int main(void)
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  ```

  See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)
- `c` must be declared as `int` because `getchar` returns `int`. See [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714)

A minor point is that instead of `int count; count = 0;`, just initialize the variable while declaring `int count = 0`. Or better yet use an `unsigned int`, because count can't be negative