# Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?

Tags: c, function

I am beginner in C programming language, recently I have studied about `getchar` function, which will **accept a character from the console or from a file, display it immediately while typing** and we need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for proceeding.

It returns the `unsigned char` that they read. If end-of-file or an error is encountered `getchar()` functions return EOF.

My question is that, When it returns `unsigned char`, then why its returned value is stored in `int` variable?

Please help me.

Comment: A good link: [Definition of EOF and how to use it effectively](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140)

Comment: See also [`while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)` loop won't stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694394/while-c-getcfile-eof-loop-wont-stop-executing/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Precisely because of that EOF-value. Because a char in a file may be any possible char value, including the null character that C-strings use for termination, `getchar()` must use a larger integer type to add an EOF-value.

It simply happens to use int for that purpose, but it could use any type with at least 9 bit.

Comment: Detail: "a char in a file may be any possible char value" --> a character may have many a possible value, but the value returned from `getchar()` is a character's  `unsigned char` value, not its `char` value.

Answer (score 4):

The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF.

EOF is a macro which expands to an integer constant expression with type int and an implementation dependent negative value but is very commonly -1.

Answer (score 2):

Read this link: [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/void+FIO34-C.+Use+int+to+capture+the+return+value+of+character+IO+functions+that+might+be+used+to+check+for+end+of+file)

Here it is written that:

> Do not convert the value returned by a character I/O function to char if that value will be compared to EOF. Once the return value of these functions has been converted to a char type, character values may be indistinguishable from EOF. Also, if sizeof(int) == sizeof(char), then the int used to capture the return value may be indistinguishable from EOF. See FIO35-C. Use feof() and ferror() to detect end-of-file and file errors when sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) for more details about when sizeof(int) == sizeof(char). See STR00-C. Represent characters using an appropriate type for more information on the proper use of character types.

This rule applies to the use of all character I/O functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getchar` returns an `int` which

- if the function is successful, represents the character code of the next character on the stream in the range of an `unsigned char` (i.e. a non-negative value), or
- if the function fails, represents the special value `EOF` (which is a negative value) to indicate failure.

The reason why `getchar` always returns

- a non-negative number for a valid character, and
- a negative number to indicate failure,

is that it must be possible to distinguish between a valid character and the special value `EOF` (which indicates failure and is not a valid character).

If you store the `int` return value of `getchar` in an `unsigned char`, then you will lose information and will no longer be able to distinguish between a valid character and the special value `EOF`.

On most platforms, `EOF` is defined as the value `-1` and an `unsigned char` can represent the range `0` to `255`. On these platforms, the following applies:

The function `getchar` can return an `int` value in the range `-1` to `255`, which is 257 possible values. The range `0` to `255` (which is 256 possible values) is used for valid character codes and the value `-1` is used to indicate failure (`EOF`).

If you store the `int` return value of `getchar` in a variable of type `unsigned char`, then you will only have 256 instead of 257 possible values. The value `-1` will be converted to the value `255`. This means that the `unsigned char` variable is unable to represent the value `EOF` and you will no longer be able to tell whether `getchar` returned the value `EOF` or whether it returned the valid character code `255`. The value `255` could mean both.

You will get a similar problem if you store the return value of `getchar` in a variable of type `signed char`, because a `signed char` is also only able to represent `256` different values, but you need to be able to represent `257` different values. Even if a `signed char` has the advantage that it is able to represent the value `EOF`, you will still have the problem that you cannot distinguish `EOF` from a valid character, because the value `-1` could mean both. It could mean `EOF` or it could mean a valid character with the character code `255`.

For this reason, you should always first store the return value of `getchar` in a variable of type `int`. Only after determining that `getchar` did not return `EOF` is it safe to store the return value in a variable of type `unsigned char` or `signed char`, because you no longer need to distingish valid characters from the special value `EOF`.

The same also applies for storing the return value of `getchar` in a `char`. On some platforms, `char` is equivalent to `signed char`, and on some other platforms, `char` is equivalent to `unsigned char`. The ISO C standard allows both.