# Extremly simple C program,why I am getting output like this?

Tags: c, getchar

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  long cn=1;
  char ch;
  while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
    printf("%ld\t%c\n",cn++,ch);
  } 
}
```

When I input word "secret" and hit enter it shows count up to 7 and not 6,why?

Comment: `EOF` must differ from any character! Thus `getchar` returns `int`, not `char`. Enable compiler warnings and take them seriously!

Comment: [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the "enter" character is read as well. This is in fact a "newline", ASCII code 10 (or hex 0A).

Comment: Thank you,I was making reading Ritchie C book and making a quiz for www.embeddedfunda.com