# 'C for Dummies' getchar() function not working

Tags: c, getchar

I'm currently in the very early stages of learning C programming and am working my way through "Beginning Programming with C for Dummies" using Code::Blocks.
The first activity in Chapter 7, *Fetching characters with `getchar()`*, asks us to copy the code exactly as it's presented in the book; see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{
    int c;

    printf("I'm waiting for a character: ");
    c = getchar();
    printf("I waited for the '%c' character.\n", c);
    return (0);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
I'm waiting for a character:
```

However according to the book, the output that I *should* be seeing is the character's ASCII code value. It then asks that I change the `%c` placeholder to `%d` to display the value, but still I get the same outcome as before. I could probably recite the code with my eyes closed I've checked it through that may times; I simply cannot see where I'm going wrong.

Am I right in thinking that the `getchar()` function isn't being recognized? Or that the code isn't being read after the first `printf` statement? Any guidance is welcome as I don't want to move on until I've understood the problem.

Comment: After you see `I'm waiting for a character:`, do you type in a character?

Comment: No - it works fine - see http://ideone.com/AlgWkH

Comment: try `printf("I'm waiting for a character: ");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Notes: `int main()` is a deprecated signature. Use prototype-style declarations: `int main(void)` (for all functions, not just `main`). `return` is not a function, but a statement. Don't use parentheses around the argument, this can result in strange error messages for typos. The function-syle was used for K&R C, today it is more of a bad habit.

Comment: First of all, you should change your `int c;` to `char c;`. Other than that, you can run your application with no problem at all.

Comment: @Prometheus you are dead wrong.

Comment: because of ..? @n.m.

Comment: @Prometheus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167/why-must-the-variable-used-to-hold-getchars-return-value-be-declared-as-int

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for your response and screen shot of my code with your output.

Comment: @4386427 I took your code from your link and pasted it into both code::blocks and IDEone, however I AGAIN got the same output as per my OP. Why would the same piece of code work differently for you than it does for me?

Comment: On ideone: Did you remember to put an ' a' into the "input" tab?

Comment: @4386427 Sorry, can you please be more specific? I've only been learning for one week :)

Comment: At ideone there are an input tab and an output tab just below the code window. After writing the code, click the input tab and type the `a` the run the program

Comment: do you enter a character on your keyboard and then press enter when you run it  on your pc?

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for your suggestion, I did what you said, it worked, but I'm not satisfied enough to move on, something is still not right. Thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: @4386427 Actually I've come to realise that your response was answer I needed, thank you so much, I can now move one :)

Answer (score 1):

Please enter any key, then 2nd printf will show the result. getchar() is expecting input from user, controller reach at 2nd line & waiting for input.