# How to populate a vector / matrix of int / size_t with NAN in C

Tags: c, matrix, vector, integer, nan

As far as I understood, `NAN` can be allocate to a `double` type variable but not necessarily to `int` / `size_t`

Is there still a way to populate a vector/matrix of type `int` / `size_t` with NAN?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t nrows, ncols;
  size_t *array;
} Matrix ;

size_t ncol = 5;
size_t nrow = 1;

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix);

int main()
{
  Matrix *mat1 = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
  mat1->nrows = nrow;
  mat1->ncols = ncol;
  mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
  if (mat1 == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
  {
    mat1->nrows = nrow;
    mat1->ncols = ncol;
    mat1->array = (size_t *) malloc(mat1->nrows * mat1->ncols * sizeof(*mat1->array));
    for (size_t row =0; row<mat1->nrows; row++)
    {
      for (size_t col =0; col<mat1->ncols; col++)
      {
        mat1->array[row * ncol + col] = NAN;
      }
    }
    print_matrix(mat1);
    free(mat1);
  }
}

void print_matrix(Matrix * matrix)
{
  for (size_t row =0; row<matrix->nrows; row++)
  {
    for (size_t col =0; col<matrix->ncols; col++)
    {
      printf("%zu ", matrix->array[row * ncol + col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: `int` and `size_t` do not have a valid value which is NAN (or equivalent), so no.

Comment: `NaN` ("not a number") is a feature of floating-point number formats, and there's no standard equivalent for any integral types. Typically people want to use all the bits of an integer for storing values. You're welcome to define an integer constant which is invalid in your specific program, for this use, but it won't behave like `NaN` in arithmetic.

Comment: Integers just doesn't have the concept of "not a number" like floating point types have. Why do you need integer NAN's? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: On a different note, please [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858) (or really any function returning `void *`).

Comment: This is like asking if I can populate a vector of type `int` with `3.1`

Comment: You can determine a specific value which you'll intepret as NAN (e.g. 999999). This value must not be one of the actual valid values for this field in your application.

Comment: And `size_t` is to be used for *sizes*, not general integer values. If you need an unsigned integer type just use plain `unsigned` (or the `long` or `long long` variants).

Comment: If it's a sentinel value you're looking for, consider `INT_MIN`. And while this reduces the range of legally usable values, it makes positive and negative range equally sized.

Comment: thank you all for all comments and answers. @Someprogrammerdude : the problem that is supposed to solved is that I would like to populate a matrix at runtime, potentially incompletely, and then I want to iterate over the matrix and have a special flag where the cells remained untouched

Comment: The C standard specifies trap representations, which can act as NaNs for integer types, but they are uncommon in modern C implementations.

Comment: That kind of sounds like you want *sparse arrays* or similar.So you can keep track of which elements are occupied and which aren't.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understood, `NAN` can be [assigned] to a `double` type variable

That is correct.  `NaN` is one of the special values defined for [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)-based types like `float` and `double`.<sup>1</sup>

> but not necessarily to `int` / `size_t`

Right.  `NaN` is *not* a value defined for integral types `int` or `size_t`.

You can't store `NaN` in an integral variable for the same reason you can't store 3.14 in an integral variable.  It's just not one of the values that integral types can hold.

(One of the formal definitions of a [*data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) in programming is that it is a set of values, and a set of operations on those values.  For types `float` and `double` — but only for those types — `NaN` is one of the values.  Actually, there are multiple `NaN` values, but that's a different story.)

For the floating-point types, `NaN`s are [*sentinel values*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value), well-defined "not a value" values.  Some types have sentinel values, and some don't.  For example, for pointer types, `NULL` is the sentinel "not a valid pointer" value.  In C strings, the null character `\0` is a sentinel value marking the end of the string.  On the other hand, when you call `getchar`, `EOF` is the "not a character" value.  (This doesn't make `EOF` a sentinel value for type `char`, though, since `EOF` is not a value of type `char`.)

But there is no predefined sentinel value for any of the other integral types.  The way integers are used in real programs, there's no value that could be reserved as a sentinel that might not also be a valid value.

If you have an integer variable and you need a sentinel value, you will need to define one of your own, if you can.  For example, if you know that your values are always positive, you can use -1 as a sentinel value.  But this will be, at best, a convention: the value -1 won't be treated specially by the language, or the CPU — it's just another integer value.

It's great that floating-point and pointer types have sentinel values, and it's sometimes a nuisance that other types don't.  The *ad hoc* conventions one has to use when trying to define sentinel values for other types frequently lead to various nuisances.  In order for `EOF` to work as a sentinel value for `getchar`, programmers have to remember to [always store `getchar`'s return value in a variable of type `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167), not `char`.  A function like [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) that returns a number of characters read, or -1 to indicate an error, is difficult to define a good return type for, since it has to be signed to accommodate -1, but could otherwise be unsigned.<sup>2</sup>  The function [`mktime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime), which converts a broken-down time structure back to an integral `time_t` value, returns -1 for error, meaning you can't unambiguously tell whether you've gotten an error, or have successfully converted the time 23:59:59 on December 31, 1969.

---

Footnote 1: Types `float` and `double` aren't *necessarily* based on the IEEE-754 definitions in C, but on most systems these days, they are.

Footnote 2: I believe that's why `read` is defined as returning a value of type `ssize_t`, and I believe type `ssize_t` is a "signed `size_t`", or in other words, "A value that would otherwise be unsigned, just like `size_t` is, except it has to be signed so it can return -1".

Comment: I do not think float or double are IEEE based. They existed long before IEEE 754. They might be coinciding  with the IEEE types on compatible CPUs (e.g. x87) and compatible compilers.

Comment: @Vladimir Right.  "Just about all machines today" (whatever that means) use IEEE-754, so it's a convenient assumption, but it's not universal.  Footnote added.

Comment: Re "I believe" in footnote 2, that is correct. Do note that `ssize_t` isn't a standard C type, though. It's a POSIX type.

Comment: `ssize_t` isn't a standard C type, although the `printf` format specifier `%zd` is standard and requires the signed integer type that corresponds to `size_t`. (Similarly `%tu` is standard and requires the unsigned integer type that corresponds to `ptrdiff_t`.) I guess that allows an implementation not to implement a signed integer type corresponding to `size_t`. (But there *is* a requirement to implement an unsigned integer type corresponding to `ptrdiff_t`.) Every signed integer type is required to have a corresponding unsigned integer type, but not the other way round!