# How to properly check for ctrl-d in user input when using fgetc(stdin) in C?

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to read user input into a buffer by using fgetc(stdin) in c.
But apparently i am using it in a wrong way, for determining if the user wants to close the program.
What am i doing wrong, and how can i check for ctrl-d correctly, to terminate my program.

My code looks like this:

```
int read_chars = 0;
while((buf[read_chars] = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    //do stuff, (change size of buf, break on \n...)
    read_chars++;
}
if(feof(stdin)) {
    printf("eof");
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}
if(ferror(stdin)) {
    printf("error");
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE), ...
}
```

This works fine, until i press ctrl-d. When i do so, "error" is immediately printed.

Comment: What is `buf` defined as?

Comment: You need an intermediate value of type `int` to read into, to reliably distinguish the value `EOF`.  If `buf` is an array of `char`, you've got the same problem described at [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167)

Comment: But there may be something else going on here.  The expected failure modes (if the variable receiving `fgetc`'s return value is incorrectly declared) are that you fail to detect EOF at all, or that you wrongly detect EOF on receipt of certain input characters such as `ÿ`.  If the problem is that you're getting an error rather than an eof condition, I'm not sure what could be causing that.

Comment: Instead of `printf("error")`, use `perror("error")`. This will append a message detailing the actual error encountered.

Comment: In my real implementation i casted the output of fgets() to char, and buf is an char array (created using calloc).

Comment: Can't reproduce on my Linux box. I got "eof" printed'

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
int c;
...
while ((c = fgetc( stdin )) != EOF )
{
  buf[read_chars++] = c;
}
```

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not `char`.  There is no `EOF` *character* as such; it's just a value indicating that there is no more input on the stream.

Answer (score 0):

After i updated my system it now works as it should (feof(stdin) is returning nonzero if ctrl-D is pressed -> the program terminates successfully).
I still don't know what caused the error, but the code works.
(Maybe it even was an other read of stdin, which put an error indicator, i cant tell, as i changed nothing and it works now)