getchar function behavior when waiting for a input
I have this code
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    char c ;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("the value in int is %d\n",c);
}

Does the getchar function block if there is nothing in stdin, and when something appears, the system raises an interrupt and then the process continues?

This question is similar to: I'm trying to understand getchar() != EOF. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Read the function manual carefully especially look at the returned datattype.

Yes, it blocks. When standard input is a terminal, then probably a (keyboard) interrupt happens. But standard input could also be connected to a pipe or some regular file. These libc functions abstract things like interrupts away.

@3CxEZiVlQ I think OP is asking about the kernel's TTY driver doing line buffering and not releasing the first char until it sees a newline

c = getchar() is very wrong! https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/995714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714

See also Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input? and while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) loop won't stop executing?


Does the getchar function block if there is nothing in stdin

Yes, if the stream cannot immediately provide the next character, and the stream is not in a state of having reached its end or in a state of error, then requesting more input on the stream with getchar will generally block.

and when something appears the system raise a interrupt and then the process continues?

Yes, getchar will return as soon as new input is available.

Side note:
The return type of getchar is int, not char. Therefore, you should not store the return value in a variable of type char. This is important for several reasons, for example because the data type char is not guaranteed to be able to represent the value EOF. See the following question for further information:
Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?

"and the stream  ... in a state of error," --> Even if the error indicator set, another character read will be attempted.  Try putchar(stdin); printf("%d\n", ferror(stdin)); and then getchar().  I am confident it will block.

Re “Yes, getchar will return as soon as new input is available.”: To answer OP’s question, when the process executes getchar and no character is available, its read request causes the system to block the process for executing. When data is available, the system allows the process to resume. There is no interrupt for the process. (Inside the operating system, there are likely interrupts involved in handling the devices, but I do not think OP intended to ask about those.)

@EricPostpischil Only the calling thread will be blocked if no character is available unless I'm mistaken.

@TedLyngmo: Agreed.
